# Android studio dont see instance of GoogleApiClient

Tags: android, google-play-services

I have added following dependencies in my `build.gradle` file:

```
dependencies {
    //compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
}
```

I have these 2 lines in `Manifest` file:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

But, `@integer/google_play_services_version` is not resolved. I  tried to put import that I found in an other question but "common" library doesn't exist. I have downloaded Google Play Services from SDK. What did I do wrong and what I should do to solve this issue?

Comment: Which gradle version r U using ? If it is 2.0 r more change to 1.5.0 & r U using multi dex ?

Comment: `dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
    }`

Comment: now I changet to1.5.0 it was 1.3.0 What next?
It still not see imports and GoogleApiClient